# Weird animation with presentViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, orientation

I have this issue when trying to change the current view on landscape mode, I have a storyboard with 2 scenes, and a Button with a custom segue to open the next view. The animation is good, but when the 2nd view appears, it seems to rotate from landscape to portrait. I have on plist Device Orientation set to landscape right, I tried with left too, but same happens. I added to the delegate (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window, I also tried with supportedOrientations on each view controller with no result. By the way this is on ios 7 with xcode 5, I don't know if this is a bug or if I missing something on this. Also, this only happens on landscape mode, portrait works good.

Thank you